# Slick way to define p.c. $f$ so that $f(e) \in W_{e}$

Tags: logic, computability

Is there a slick way to define a partial computable function $f$ so that $f(e) \in W_{e}$ whenever $W_{e} \neq \emptyset$? (Here $W_{e}$ denotes the $e^{\text{th}}$ c.e. set.) My only solution is to start by defining $g(e) = \mu s [W_{e,s} \neq \emptyset]$, where $W_{e,s}$ denotes the $s^{\text{th}}$ finite approximation to $W_{e}$, and then set
$$
f(e) = \begin{cases}
\mu y [y \in W_{e, g(e)}] &\text{if } W_{e} \neq \emptyset \\
\uparrow &\text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
but this is ugly (and hence not slick).

Comment: @Quinn: Your approach looks clean and natural, more or less the opposite of ugly.

Comment: @user6312 Ya, I should pin down exactly why I think my approach is ugly. I was hoping that someone would present a slick(er) solution that would make this clear.

Comment: I agree - implicitly the only think you can do is wait until the process that generates $W_e$ actually enumerates something, and, since it might never enumerate another element, you really can almost only choose $f(e)$ as, in some sense, the "first" element of $W_e$ which gets enumerated.  If $W_{e,s+1}-W_{e,s}$ can have cardinality greater than $1$, you need some way to select an element of the difference, and $\mu$ is the easiest way to do so.

Comment: I would add that the definition of $f(e)$ should probably actually be: "If $g(e)\downarrow$," rather than "If $W_e\neq \emptyset$" to be effective.

Comment: @Thomas How do you know this is the "only thing" one can do?

Comment: @Quinn: Well, you could do something much more complicated, but (1) It has to do the right thing when $W_e$ is a singleton.  (2) The set of $e$ such that $W_e$ is a singleton is not r.e. (3) So, impliclty, any  $f(e)$ solving your problem is going to have the property that for infinitely many $e$, $f(e)\downarrow$, $f(e)$ is the first enumerated element of $W_e$ and $W_e$ is not a singleton.

Comment: @Quinn: Mind you, you could use a different sequence $V_{e,s}$ which enumerates the $W_e$ in some nice way, but it will essentially need to fall back to the same approach.

Comment: I don't see what the question is here; could you edit it?  What do you mean by "slick"? Your method is almost an equation for computing the function, what more could you want?

Comment: @Carl I admit that the question is vague. However, there is something unsettling about the function written. I think it has something to do with the fact that there are two uses of the $\mu$ operator. Moreover, I'd like to see it written without having to define $g$ ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can at least show you how to get that down to one use of the $\mu$ operator. Based on the response to my comment above this might be what you want.

Following your construction in sprit, let $h$ perform the following computation on input $e$. It computes $\phi_e(0)$ for one step; then $\phi_e(0)$ and $\phi_e(1)$ for two steps each; then $\phi_e(0)$, $\phi_e(1)$, and $\phi_e(2)$ for three steps each; and so on. During this computation, if it ever happens that we see $\phi_e(i)$ converge to some number $j$, we let $h(e)$ return $j$. Otherwise, if $\phi_e(n)$ never converges for any $n$, $h(e)$ will be undefined.  So $h(e) \in W_e$ whenever $W_e$ is nonempty, because $W_e$ is defined as the range of $\phi_e$.

Because $h$ is computable, it has some index $l$. Let
$$
f(e) = U(\mu s.T(l, e, s))
$$
where $T$ and $U$ are Kleene's functions (as in [1]). In fact we have $f \simeq h$ by the definition of these functions. This is what I meant when I said in my comment that your construction is almost an equational definition of $f$.

1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the reason your solution seems ugly to you is that you appear to be excessively concerned with the formalism of representing your computable function in terms of the $\mu$ operator. The essence of computability, however,  does not lie with this formalism, but rather with the idea of a computable procedure. It is much easier and more enlightening to see that a function is computable simply by describing an algorithm that computes it, and such kind of arguments are pervasive in computability theory. (One can view them philosophically as instances of the [Church-Turing thesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Turing_thesis).)

The set $W_e$ consists of the numbers that are eventually accepted by program $e$. These  are the [computabley enumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) sets, in the sense that there is a uniform computable procedure to enumerate their elements.

We may now  define the desired function $f$ by the following computable procedure: on input $e$, start enumerating $W_e$. When the first element appears, call it $f(e)$.

It is now clear both that $f$ is computable and that  $f(e)\in W_e$ whenever $W_e$ is not empty, as desired.